# Using random images from database to fill up whole web page height and width

Tags: html, css

I'd look to pull X number of images from my DB anything from 100 +/- images, and I'd like to take up the whole page from top left corner to bottom right corner

so far i got this

```
<? $images .= "<img src='".$image."' width='64' height='64' style="float:left;"/>";?> 

<div style="position: absolute; top:0px; left:0px;" ><?=$images;?></div>
```

But this code doesn't fill all the way to the right and bottom

Comment: Why are you not using the body element with `padding:0;width:100%;height:100%`?

Answer (score 1):

This a NP-Hard problem. What you want is a greedy algorithm to fill each row of your screen with a random image when only the the width of your screen is the limiting value. I've written a bin-packing solution for this problem. You are welcome to download my package bin-packing at phpclasses.org.

Answer (score 1):

I would look in to [jQuery Masonry](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/). It has the ability to fill a page by moving the div containers around to build a wall (as masonry implies). I think that's what you're going for, at least if they're all not 64/6x pixels (allows you to be flexible with image sizes).

*[Demo can be found here](http://desandro.com/demo/masonry/docs/)*

Otherwise, you may just making each element display inline and allow the browser to populate the area.